# microgear client is stuck on connection

Tags: python, iot, gpio

Using https://github.com/netpieio/microgear-python

My code:

```py
import microgear.client as microgear
import RPi.GPIO as gpio
import time
import logging

DT=27
SCK=17
m1=12
m2=16
HIGHT=1
LOW=0
sample=0
val=0

appid='Locacell'
gearkey='xxx'
gearsecret='xxx'

microgear.create(gearkey,gearsecret,appid,{"debugmode":True})

def connection():
    logging.debug("connect")
def subscription(topic,message):
    logging.debug(topic+" "+message)
def disconnect():
    logging.debug("disconnect")
microgear.setalias("can")
microgear.on_connect= connection
microgear.on_message= subscription
microgear.on_disconnect= disconnect
microgear.subscribe("/can")
microgear.connect(True)

gpio.setwarning(True)
gpio.setmode(gpio.BCM)
gpio.setup(m1, gpio.OUT)
gpio.setup(m2, gpio.OUT)
gpio.setup(SCK, gpio.OUT)
gpio.output(m1, 0)
gpio.output(m2, 0)

def readCount():
    i=0
    Count=0
print Count
time.sleep(1)
```

Output is:

[image: program output]

... but then it stopped.

Comment: To show your code in question press the {} and in the "enter code here" paste your code

Comment: Alternatively, use code-blocks to format your code - three backticks on the lines before and after. Please take some time to read [ask] and [formatting help](/help/formatting). Your question is unreadable as it stands.

Comment: AFAICT your code is working exactly as expected, and waiting for some gpio or other external event

Comment: I fixed the formatting, but please add some description and explanation what `microgear` is maybe we can find or add some tags for that.

Comment: I use raspberry pi post parameter from module hx711 and loadcell to my website

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be some type of MQTT equivalent.

Your code is subscribed to a topic, and intentionally hangs. There needs to be a second application that is responsible for sending events to the server (netpie.io), then that'll trigger the `subscription` function assigned to your `microgear.on_message` handler. As it stands, `readCount` doesn't do anything, and you'll need to scope the count variable outside of any function to use it.

[There's docs here that you'll need to translate](https://github.com/netpieio/microgear-python/wiki/%E0%B8%81%E0%B8%B2%E0%B8%A3%E0%B9%83%E0%B8%8A%E0%B9%89%E0%B8%87%E0%B8%B2%E0%B8%99%E0%B9%83%E0%B8%AB%E0%B9%89%E0%B8%AA%E0%B9%88%E0%B8%87%E0%B8%82%E0%B9%89%E0%B8%AD%E0%B8%A1%E0%B8%B9%E0%B8%A5%E0%B8%AD%E0%B8%A2%E0%B9%88%E0%B8%B2%E0%B8%87%E0%B8%95%E0%B9%88%E0%B8%AD%E0%B9%80%E0%B8%99%E0%B8%B7%E0%B9%88%E0%B8%AD%E0%B8%87)

Comment: you mean? socket

Comment: Sockets don't have subscriptions or topics, specifically, `microgear.subscribe("/can")`. But yes, you're using sockets behind the scenes

Comment: You can see in the source code, it is MQTT https://github.com/netpieio/microgear-python/blob/master/microgear/client.py#L124